# Jquery Layout Plugin How to determine whether a pane is open or closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using `jquery.layout-1.2.0` by *Fabrizio Balliano*

i want to know in my `java script` whether a Layout Pane is in open state or closed state.

As per documentation i tried the following.

```
var lout = $('body').layout();
// get layout 'state'
var is_west_open = lout.state.west.isOpen;
alert(is_west_open);
if (!is_west_open)
  outerLayout.toggle('west');
```

Alert is returning '`Undefined`'

What did i miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right. There's no duplicate property `isOpen`. Use `NOT isClosed` instead:

```
var is_west_open = ( ! lout.state.west.isClosed);
```

I am not ready to answer why is there no property isOpen (I dont watch on this js-library), but I'd like to give you 2 advices:

1) Use `console.log(<variable>)` instead of `alert(<variable>)`.

- First of all, it doesn't stop execution of the script, so you can see few log-messages at a time rather than clicking "OK" any time an `alert` happens;
- You can back to the previous message;
- Alert accepts a String, so any element provided is converted automatically with `toString()` method, so it is not exactly the same object that browser operate with;

2) Try to use Developer Tools in Google Chrome or Firebug (in Firefox) or, in Opera and IE their native inspectors - it can enshort the time you debug your application - they show you all the properties and methods available for an object

Just Click `F12` and you'll can see something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlSga.png